# GraphQL - do not return empty objects of an interface

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js

Given

```
interface Interface {
  common: String!
}

type A implements Interface {
  common: String!
  foo: String!
}

type B implements Interface {
  common: String!
  bar: String!
}
```

Is it possible to construct a query, which by default returns `[Interface]` to only return `A`s, and filter out `B`s / empty objects?

When there is an `A` and a `B` in the results set

```
query {
  q {
    ... on A {
      foo 
    }
  }
}
```

Returns an `A` and an empty object (since we asked for no data in other cases):

```
{
  "data": {
    "q": [
      {
        "foo": "foo"
      },
      {}
    ]
  }
}
```

See https://launchpad.graphql.com/zrz504kp37 for the full example.

Comment: you can do it. but whats the differentiating factor for determining A or B? or you can check for empty object in resolver function and remove those entries and return remaining

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but in my case I used GraphQL (PHP) with a symfony bundle called **overblog/GraphQLBundle** which provide some callbacks (events), in my case I used the post execute one:

```
public function onPostExecutor(ExecutorResultEvent $event)
{
    $result = $event->getResult();

    // Here I loop over the data array and unset all these empty {} objects.
}
```

This is the doc for reference:
https://github.com/overblog/GraphQLBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/events/index.md

I guess you could used something similar for JS.